# Gridview smooth scroll and image population from the system gallery

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gallery, android-cursoradapter, smooth-scrolling

I have created a gallery. I am populating a gridview from a simple cursor adapter (custom implementation).

First issue is that gridview stucks in the middle while scrolling. I think its because images are binded to a view continuously on user interaction. How can I achieve a smooth scroll?

Secondly I do not get all the images from the gallery through the Cursor. What do I need to do in order to get all the images. I also observed that this code does not return images on different devices, such as Samsung Galaxy s2. Works fine on Samsung Note 2 and Nexus 4 though. URI is same though: content://media/external/images/thumbnails

Code for an adapter:

```
/**  
 * @author Syed Ahmed Hussain
 */
public class CustomGalleryAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private int mImageIdColumnIndex;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayout;

    public CustomGalleryAdapter(Context pContext, int pLayout, Cursor pCursor, String[] pFrom, int[] pTo, int pFlags) {
        super(pContext, pLayout, pCursor, pFrom, pTo, pFlags);
        mLayout             = pLayout;
        mContext            = pContext;
        mLayoutInflater     = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mContentResolver    = mContext.getContentResolver();
        mImageIdColumnIndex = pCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context pContext, Cursor pCursor, ViewGroup pParent) {
        return mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View pView, Context pContext, Cursor pCursor) {
        long id = pCursor.getLong(mImageIdColumnIndex);
        mImageView = (ImageView) pView;
        mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContentResolver, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, new Options()));
    }

}
```

Code for an activity:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID };
    private CustomGalleryAdapter mCustomGalleryAdapter;
    private String[] selectionArgs = null;
    private String selection = "";
    private GridView mGridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_gallery);
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int pId, Bundle pArgs) {

        return new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> pLoader, Cursor pData) {
        mCustomGalleryAdapter = new CustomGalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.gallery_item, pData, projection, new int[] { R.id.galleryImageView }, 0);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mCustomGalleryAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> pLoader) {

    }

}
```

View_Galler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:id="@+id/gridView" />
```

gallery_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/galleryImageView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Can anyone please guide me on what am I doing wrong? and how can I solve these problems?

Comment: Think you have to use cache memory http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: In this scenario images are fetched directly from database. Only delay is when we call getThumbnail(...);. How will caching work here with such an implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the improvements you can try:

1. Using ArrayAdapter.
2. Using ViewHolder pattern for reusing view in grid cells and reusing convertview in getView is cruicial (**)
3. Avoid to instantiating unnessary objects inside adapter getView.
4. Caching the imgaes if you are downloading from internet using LazyLoading technique and with Async tasks.
5. Using compressed images in both case when you are alos using images fom local resource.
6. android:fastScrollEnabled="true".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **Universal Image Loader**

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Also use:
`android:largeHeap="true"` in your Manifest.

Declare this attribute in your GridView (XML) `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`